# I signed up via my Google account and now can't get on Trello

Tags: gmail, trello, login

I signed up via my Google account but now when I try to login via my Google account Trello just loops back to the login page.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Just successfully logged into Trello with my Google account. Are you sure you signed up via Google? Have you tried a different browser (maybe a cookie issue)?

Answer (score 2):

I had the very same problem but it was only affecting my ability to log into Trello using my Google Apps credentials AND on Google Chrome. I believe it was some strange redirect problem. In any case, I solved it as follows:

1. Logged into Trello using FireFox and my Google Apps Credentials
2. Opened a board
3. Copy the URL for that board
4. Attempt to log into Trello using Chrome
5. Paste the URL into Chrome

Comment: You can also type in your Gmail address as the company address and then click on Sign in with Google on the next step.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't be able to get out of the loop, but finally I could!

1. Open Trello
2. Use the menu from above (on Mac)
3. Choose "File"
4. Choose "New Window"